# Scan for Class Name on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to search an entire web page for `class="error"`, and if it doesn't exist, change `error = true` to `error = false`.

How can I do this with jQuery? I have a vague feeling I can do it with `.each();` somehow, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Couldn't you just check to see if the selector returns anything?

Comment: If it doesn't exist how do you expect to change it from `error=true` to `error= false`?

Comment: Sometimes it does exist. I wrote a simple jQuery form validator. If the user tries to submit the form without filling everything out, the fields that aren't filled out get the class "error" added to them, and the form won't submit with the  variable "error" set to true. So I need a way to remove the error class, and change the variable to false.

Answer (score 8):

This is the shortest way:

```
var error = $(".error").length > 0;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Won't let me accept for another 7 minutes or so, but I'll accept then.